Is it always true, when $\forall x \phi \vDash \phi [\frac{x}{y}]$ where y is any L-Term
If phi is always true for all x in phi (if any) is phi also true if you replace all x with a random L-Term, which my university defines as a variable, a constant, or a function of variables, constants or functions.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Yes, if $\phi$ is always true, it is true also of an object $a$ whatever, and terms are names of objects.
See Universal instantiation.
